# Flutter - How to check a value after delay in a listener?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Here's my code:

```
networkConnectivity.listen((value) async {
      print("Before: $value");
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      print("Later: $value");
      if (!value) {
        ...
      } else {
        ..
      }
    });
```

Let's say the listener gets triggered when there's no internet and **`Before`** value is `false`. But even if **`Before`** value is already changed to `true` within 5 seconds, **`Later`** remains false.

Why am I not getting the updated value in this situation? What's the workaround?

Comment: The callback you provide to the listen function: (value) async ... will get called every time the networkConnectivity decides to notify its listeners. You don't have to put some kind of delay in there, the delay is inside the same listener callback instance and will have the same value. Without knowing where the networkConnectivity instance is coming from i can't tell you what the exact problem is!

Comment: Oh yeah I misinterpreted completely what you wanted. @kounex answer/comment is what you want

Comment: What I want to do is I want to show a dialog if the connection is unavailable for more than 5 seconds. Hence the delay. @kounex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your latest response where you want to show a dialog once the listener calls the provided callback with false (no connection) and the callback won't be called with the value true within 5 seconds, the following approach might be what you want:

```dart
Timer noConnectivityTimer;

...

networkConnectivity.listen((value) async {
    if (!value && (noConnectivityTimer == null || !noConnectivityTimer.isActive)) {
        noConnectivityTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => showDialog(...));
    } else {
        noConnectivityTimer?.cancel();
        ...
    }
  },
);
```

What i did: making use of the `Timer` class where i can define a `Duration` where a callback (defined right after) will be called once the given duration has been reached - we will show the dialog there. But if our listener callback gets a value which is true, indicating we have a connection again, we want to cancel any running `Timer` so the dialog is only shown when we received a false value initially and no true value within 5 seconds. You might want to edit this as you need it in your app, this is just an example!

Answer (score 0):

A variable's value won't change unless something changes it.  In the code you provide, nothing change the value of 'value' between your two prints.

Presumably, what will happen when the connectivity changes, is that your code block will run again, with a new value in the 'value' variable.

Comment: What I didn't get is how come the last *Before* value be `true` and *Later* be `false`. 
What I want to do is I want to show a dialog if the connection is unavailable for more than 5 seconds. Hence the delay.